# stack overflow with std::make_unique but not with raw pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I would like to allocate a big object (a `bitset<1000000000>`). As owning raw pointers are to be avoided, I tried the following declaration:

```
auto foo()->std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<MAX>>;
...
{
    auto bar = foo();
}
```

which gives a stack overflow error (the compiler is VS2013). But

```
auto foo()->std::bitset<MAX>*;
...
{
    auto bar = foo();
    ...
    delete bar;
}
```

does not.

The implementation of `foo()` looks like:

```
auto is_prime = 
        //std::make_unique<std::bitset<MAX>>(std::bitset<MAX>{});
        // or:
        new std::bitset<MAX>{};
is_prime->set();

(*is_prime)[0] = (*is_prime)[1] = false;

auto max_i = static_cast<int>(std::sqrt(MAX)) + 1;
for (auto i = 1; i < max_i; i++) {
        if ((*is_prime)[i]) {
                for (auto j = i * i; j < MAX; j += i) {
                        (*is_prime)[j] = false;
                }
        }
}

return is_prime;
```

What is the obvious thing I missed?

Comment: what's the implementation of `foo()` look like?

Comment: @BobFincheimer I added it. It is just a prime sieve, nothing exotic really.

Comment: @dyp: I thought that too, then realized each example is a declaration followed by a compound statement presumably in some other function.

Comment: @aschepler Just saw it, thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
auto is_prime = 
   std::make_unique<std::bitset<MAX>>(std::bitset<MAX>{});
```

This line creates a temporary bitset object (`std::bitset<MAX>{}`) on the stack and then passes that to the copy constructor of the `new`-ed object on the heap.

To just use the default constructor, you want:

```
auto is_prime = std::make_unique<std::bitset<MAX>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
typdef std::bitset<1000000> BS;
std::make_unique<BS>(BS())
```

you create a rather sizeable object on the stack: the temporary object being copied! Depending on how much you already have on the tve stack or how big the stack is, this may easily cause a stack-overflow. For the operation directly allocating memory there is no temporary on tge stack.

The simple fix to the problem is to just use

```
std::make_unique<BS>()
```

as this should result in the default constructor of the heap allocated object to be called.